# How can I complete a Druid Task?

Tags: apache-kafka, ambari, druid

I import some data on my Druid Datasource. For that, I use Nifi and Tranquility for streaming injection with minute granularity (for my tests).

I've Ambari for check all my tasks and their status.

All my data are imported on my Datasource correctly and i can request them with Hive query.
When I look my tasks on Ambari, all of them are running, they are never "Complete". If I want to complete one of them, I have to kill it but I loose my data and status task is "FAILED".

I would like to understand what can I do for complete my tasks with success.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem.

In my tranquility conf, I had declared a big value for the `"WindowPeriod"`.

In fact, the task automatically ends when the `"WindowPeriod"` end.

For example, `"WindowPeriod":"PT10M"` means that the task will end in 10 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Glad that you figured it out! Just want to call out for anyone reading this that Tranquility is deprecated. The streaming ingestion services such as https://druid.apache.org/docs/latest/development/extensions-core/kafka-ingestion should be proffered for anyone starting a new deployment.